# Integrate multiples projects in one big project (Ionic 3)

Tags: git, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Ok, so the best way to communicate this is an example:

In our company, we are 9 developers and 3 persons in each team. We are developing an Ionic 3 project that consists of 3 pages or components:

1. The Dashboard page (Team A)
2. The Contact page (Team B)
3. The Login and Register page (Team C)

Each team creates a repository with his project (ionic start myPage).

Now we want to integrate automatically the project of each team in one Ionic 3 Project.

[image]

*(Of course this is only an example and the team will manage more complex modules)*

So, the question now is: 
**What is the best way of integrating each project automatically?**

Maybe using an NPM or Bower? If anyone had an example I really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found [this article](https://medium.com/@benorama/hybrid-mobile-apps-sharing-logic-between-angular2-and-ionic2-apps-7c32145b90d5) pretty useful. I used something pretty similar. I think it would still apply in your case. You'd probably have to do some tweaking

Answer (score 0):

A generic centralized collaboration flow would work. There's nothing specific for Ionic that you would need.

Just create 1 git repository and everyone can push commits there. (You could start from a template)

If you want to keep your work really separate, you could hold your separate `feature` branches. And merge / cherry-pick to master when you are done.

Create a build and tests and make sure they don't break in mainline, so other teams are never blocked.

EDIT. You should not keep different repositories for this. DO NOT do it. Your team(s) are fairly small.

---